# Models keep turning white - Unity 5.3.5p1

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm using Unit 5.3.5p1 but for some reason my models randomly turn white after I build an exe to run outside the editor.

The textures work perfectly fine within the editor, but as soon as I build and run outside - they sometimes show with appropriate colour, but many times do not and end up blank white.

Does anyone know what might be causing this in general? I've downloaded the latest unity shaders and replaced all current shaders. Currently I'm using the Standard shader only, and it is 100% unmodified.

[image]